# kotlin flow how to drop old value if the same type is on the flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

let us say I have flow like this

```
 val myflow = flow{
        emit("s1")
        emit("s2") 
        emit("s2") 
        emit("s2")
        emit(2)
    }
```

I want to collect
**s1,s2(third),2** , I want to drop first,seconds s2

Comment: At the moment when you get the first of the three `s1` values, how can you determine without looking into the future that there will be more of the same values and that it needs to be dropped? If it does not matter which one of the identical values will be collected, you can use [distinctUntilChanged](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/distinct-until-changed.html) function.

Comment: I believe this related to emiiter side not collector(future)

Comment: If you’re talking about the emission side, then you need to solve this filtering problem before you even emit to the Flow. It depends on what you’re doing to surface new values to emit what the logic would be to filter out items that you know are going to be repeated.

Comment: I do believe this also can be done on the collectors,  collectLastest is doing a very similar job however it will skip all types (s1,s2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished a couple of ways.

Using your example Flow, we can add a call to `distinctUntilChanged` before the `collect` and it will only output values that are not sequentially duplicated

```
    myFlow.distinctUntilChanged().collect {
        println("Distinct collect: $it")
    }

    /*
      Distinct collect: s1
      Distinct collect: s2
      Distinct collect: 2
     */
```

`distinctUntilChanged` also can accept a lambda, so you can compare the old and new on your own rules to pass items through the filter.

We can also do this with a hot flow.
These only send newly added values after a subscriber is started, and never close themselves until the coroutine is canceled.

```
fun test_distinct() = runTest {
    val stateFlow: MutableStateFlow<Any> = MutableStateFlow("s1")

    launch {
        stateFlow.collect {
            println("StateFlow: $it")
        }
    }

    launch {
        stateFlow.emitDelay("s2")
        stateFlow.emitDelay("s2")
        stateFlow.emitDelay("s2")
        stateFlow.emitDelay("s2")
        stateFlow.emitDelay(2)
        stateFlow.emitDelay(2)
        stateFlow.emitDelay("s2")
        stateFlow.emitDelay("s1")
        stateFlow.emitDelay("Other")
        stateFlow.emitDelay("Test")
        stateFlow.emitDelay("Semi")
    }
    /*
        StateFlow: s1
        StateFlow: s2
        StateFlow: 2
        StateFlow: s2
        StateFlow: s1
        StateFlow: Other
        StateFlow: Test
        StateFlow: Semi
     */
}

suspend fun MutableStateFlow<Any>.emitDelay(value: Any) {
    delay(400)
    emit(value)
}
```

Here I made the emit delay function just to exemplify the way the state is updated. Otherwise it doesn't get each change as effectively in a test environment. This MutableStateFlow will stay open until `currentCoroutineContext().cancel()` is called from the scope that the MutableStateFlow is being collected in.

If the values must be unique to the entire lifetime of a flow.... You can then have a list of seen values that you can reference in a filter function.

```
fun test_distinct() = runTest {
    val flowValues = mutableListOf<Any>()
    val myFlow = flow {
        emit("s1")
        emit("s2")
        emit("s2")
        emit("s2")
        emit("s1")
        emit(2)
        emit(3)
        emit("s1")
    }

    myFlow.filter {
        if (flowValues.contains(it)) false
        else {
            flowValues.add(it)
            true
        }
    }.collect {
        println("Distinct for lifetime: $it")
    }
    
    /*
        Distinct for lifetime: s1
        Distinct for lifetime: s2
        Distinct for lifetime: 2
        Distinct for lifetime: 3
     */
```